# perl - Replacing field values with hash

Tags: perl

I need to replace values in txt file's column based on the value of column 2.

I have example_data.txt file:

```
Name   Group Value
 ID1    1      1.00
 ID2    1      2.00
 ID3    1      3.00
 ID4    1      4.00
 ID5    2      5.00
 ID6    2      6.00
......................
ID10   10      7.00
```

And example_values.csv file, which is comma-separated:

```
1,6.00
2,7.00
......
10,15.00
```

Replaced file should look like this:

```
Name   Group Value
 ID1    1      6.00
 ID2    1      6.00
 ID3    1      6.00
 ID4    1      6.00
 ID5    2      7.00
 ID6    2      7.00
......................
ID10   10     15.00
```

Keeping format and number of spaces between fields is important.

So far I have come up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


open(VAL, "<", "example_values.csv") or die $!;
my %hash;
%hash = ( %hash, (split(/,/, $_))) while ( <VAL> );


my $file = '<example_data.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
open OUT, ">values_replaced.txt";
my @F = ();
my $k = ();
my %F = ();

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    if ($line =~ /ID/) {   
        my @fields = split " ";
        s/$F[1]/%hash($k){$F[0]}/; 
        print OUT $line; 
    } else {
        print OUT $line;
    }
}

close(OUT) || die "Couldn't close OUT properly";
```

Error message I get is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $F[1] in regexp compilation at perl.pl line 22, <$info> line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at perl.pl line 22, <$info> line 18.
```

But OUT file is written and it's simply copy of input file.

I appreciate any help, I am new to perl and really stuck now.

Comment: You initialize `@F = ();`, then never assign/push anything else to the array. What value did you expect to find in `$F[1]`, and how did you expect it to get there?

Comment: You have clearly used a bunch of different sources to come up with this code. There are a few issues here. What is `$k` supposed to do?

Comment: Is the table-like file tab-delimited?

Comment: You should choose between bareword file handles like `VAL` and lexical ones like `$info` and stick to it. Don't mix them up. (And your choice should be lexical handles.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is homework. I'm going to provide a working solution and explanation, but I hope I don't have to remind you that you should try to solve this yourself rather than having someone else do it for you.

- it's good that you have `use strict` and `use warnings` :)
- you are mixing lexical filehandles (`$fh`) and old-fashioned GLOB ones (`OUT`). Just use the lexical ones, and [always use three-argument open](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) like `open my $fh, '<', 'in.csv';`
- the construct you are using to read from `VAL` is very *Perlish*, but as Borodin points out it is extremely inefficient, because it merges and constructs a fresh hash with every iteration. I am also not sure if you can explain it. If you want to go for fancy Perl stuff, use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) instead. It's easier to explain what that does. ;)
- `close ... || die` might work, but you should rather use `or`. There is a difference. `and` and `or` are less *sticky*. That is called *precedence*. See in perlop [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-And).
- you are declaring variables outside of the loop that you never use

  - always declare variables in the smallest lexical scope
  - use meaningful variable names. `$k` is or `@F` are not
  - do not create two variables with the same name. It's ok to have `%F` and `@F` for Perl, but you will most certainly mix it up.
- in your `while` loop you are [`split`ting](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) into a different variable, and you are using `$_` as the input of `split`. But because you are assigning `$line` in the head of the loop, that is `undef`.
- because you are splitting on a single space, you will end up with a lot of `undef` fields. Try to use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) or better [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) to output what is in `@fields`
- you are trying to replace stuff that with variables that are never filled
- the substitution part of the `s///` has invalid syntax. It will try to replace with the literal `'%hash(){}'` where there is an `undef` warning in the parenthesis because `$k` is empty, and another `undef` warning because of `$F[0]`.
- that substitution is also trying to work on `$_`
- since you are aiming on replacing on `$line` you can skip the `else` and just print `$line` after the loop, regardless of it has been substituted or not
- it's nice to `close` your filehandles, but be consistent and close all of them

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;    # always die when open fails

# Slurp the mapping. This works on $_ and returns a list
# that ends up in the hash.
open my $fh_values, "<", "scratch/example_values.txt";
my %group_value_map = map { chomp; split /,/; } (<$fh_values>);
close $fh_values;

open my $fh_out, '>', '...';

my $file = 'scratch/example_data.txt';
open my $fh_in, '<', $file;

while ( my $line = <$fh_in> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /ID/ ) {
        # split in " " discards preceeding whitespace and splits
        # on arbitrary long whitespace sequences (but only if you
        # use it on the right variable)
        my @fields = split " ", $line;

        # This replacement works nicely now, but will break horribly
        # in case an additional column is added :)
        $line =~ s/$fields[2]/$group_value_map{$fields[1]}/;
    }

    # since we modified $line we don't need an else block that prints the
    # same value as the last line of the then block
    print $line;
}

close $fh_in;
close $fh_out;
```

**Output:**

```
Name   Group Value
 ID1    1      6.00
 ID2    1      6.00
 ID3    1      6.00
 ID4    1      6.00
 ID5    2      7.00
 ID6    2      7.00
ID10   10      15.00
```

Comment: *“the construct you are using to read from VAL is nice”* I wouldn't go as far as *nice*. It's hideously inefficient

Comment: Can I offer `split /\s+/ ; shift if...` can be replaced with `split;` - it defaults to `' '` as the delimiter which skips leading whitespace.

Comment: @sob go ahead. I'm on my phone. Change it :-)

Comment: @Borodin I changed that phrase. You're right that I was not clear on that. Thank you.

Comment: @Sobrique thanks for changing it. Next time update the comment as well, it didn't fit with your edit  ;-)

Comment: Just read about the `split ' '`. It says from 5.18 it works with any expression that evaluates to `" "`, but before it had to be `" "`, so it's safer to use the double quotes instead of `' '` because we don't know which version of Perl OP has. Not sure though if the doc means that `q{ }` will not work in older Perls, or that even `' '` will not work. Can't test right now either.